# comparing the array

Tags: php, arrays, apriori

**I have two arrays as follows:**

```
$cmobine = array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => KAWAT LOKET 1/2 HIJAU 10M
            [1] => KAWAT LOKET 1/4 HIJAU 10M
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => KAWAT LOKET 1/2 HIJAU 10M
            [1] => KUAS ETERNA 4"
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => KAWAT LOKET 1/2 HIJAU 10M
            [1] => SIKU LUBANG
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => SIKU LUBANG
            [1] => KUAS ETERNA 4"
        )
)
```

**And a second array:**

```
$transaction = array (
  [003352] => Array
        (
            [0] => KAWAT LOKET 1/2 HIJAU 10M
            [1] => KAWAT LOKET 1/4 HIJAU 10M
        )

  [003353] => Array
        (
            [0] => BODI LIDAH PELOR SS 2036-402 SES
            [1] => KAWAT LOKET 1/2 HIJAU 10M
            [2] => SIKU LUBANG
        )

  [003363] => Array
        (
            [0] => ENGSEL TIPIS BRAS 2 + SKRUP
            [1] => ENGSEL TIPIS BRAS 2 1/2 + SKRUP
            [2] => KUAS ETERNA 4"
            [3] => LAMSKAR SN
            [4] => MASKER HIDUNG
            [5] => OBENG BB ANOVI
            [6] => PAKU BETON  30
            [7] => PAKU BETON HITAM 50
            [8] => SIKU LUBANG
            [9] => PAKU BETON PUTIH 5
            [10] => SARINGAN GOT STAINLIS NISHIO
        )

  [003366] => Array
        (
            [0] => GRENDEL BABET GP 2" GOMEO
            [1] => GRENDEL STANLIS IMPERIAL 2"
        )
);
```

**then produces an array like this in accordance with the comparison array:**

```
$result = array (

    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => KAWAT LOKET 1/2 HIJAU 10M
            [1] => KAWAT LOKET 1/4 HIJAU 10M
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => KAWAT LOKET 1/2 HIJAU 10M
            [1] => SIKU LUBANG
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => SIKU LUBANG
            [1] => KUAS ETERNA 4"
        )
);
```

`$ombine` value of compared with `$transaction` value and if there is a match, then the result is the value of `$combine` itself. 
according to the `$results` above.

Comment: Are you asking for help generating the output array? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Using [array_diff_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php)  may help in this case.